# vb.net - Need help enumerating files fast on entire c drive

Tags: vb.net, directory, enumerate, getfiles

I know that I have 350808 files on my C drive that I can access using getfile and getdirectory functions, but that way it takes about 3 hours to recurse the entire drive. I read that using enumerate functions is much faster, but it seems to only go down about 1300 files, then it quits.
Here is my code:

```
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(ProjDir & "TestFour.txt", False)
    Try
        Dim dirPrograms As New DirectoryInfo(FirstDir)
        Dim dirs = From dir In dirPrograms.EnumerateDirectories()
        For Each d As DirectoryInfo In dirs
            sw.WriteLine("{0}", d.FullName)
            Dim DirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(d.FullName)
            Dim files = From f In DirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            For Each f In files
                sw.WriteLine(f.FullName)
                fPath = f.DirectoryName
                fName = f.Name
                fSize = f.Length
                fCre = f.CreationTime
                fMod = f.LastAccessTime
                sw.WriteLine("{0}*{1}*{2}*{3}*{4}", fPath, fName, fSize, fCre, fMod)
            Next
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
    Process.Start(ProjDir & "testFour.txt")
    sw.Close()
    sw.Dispose()
```

Why does it stop at about 1300 files?  How can I fix my code to recurse the entire C drive and not just the first ten directories?

Comment: Don't use `AllDirectories` but go through the dirrectory tree manually. Then you can catch possible IO-Exeptions in the `For Each`

Comment: How fast is it if you don't write to the stream?

Comment: The enumerate functions aren't going to be much faster if you're searching through all files.  Their main advantage is that they can be exited before the full directory is searched, but if you're going to read through until the end anyway, there's not a big advantage there.  I'd expect that they'd have less of an impact of memory management, so you may see a slight performance gain there, but obviously the disk access if the big culprit in this case, not memory usage.

Comment: If you want to know why your code doesn't process all files, get rid of the Try/Catch (or do something useful in the Catch block). It is likely that the problem with permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own recursive method for enumerating files and run this method in task.

```
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim searcher As New Task(Of IList(Of String))(Function()
                                                    Return GetFiles("C:\", "*.txt")
                                                  End Function)
    searcher.Start()
    Console.WriteLine("Searching for .txt files in C:\ and all subdirectories...")
    searcher.Wait()
    Dim files = searcher.Result
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N0} .txt files found.", files.Count))
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
  Function GetFiles(directoryPath As String, filter As String) As IList(Of String)
    Dim files As New List(Of String)
    Dim directories() As String = Nothing
    Try
      files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, filter))
      directories = Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Console.WriteLine($"Error while processing folder {directoryPath}.")
    End Try
    If directories IsNot Nothing Then
      For Each directory In directories
        files.AddRange(GetFiles(directory, filter))
      Next
    End If
    Return files
  End Function
End Module
```